# How to pass a guid or string from $.post(...) method without a form?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoStuff(string input) { ... }
```

The invocation by the following script reaches the method **but** the *input* parameter is *null*. I've tested all the below variations, with the same result each time.

```
$.post("/DoStuff", "{input=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583}", function() {})
$.post("/DoStuff", "{input:bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583}", function() {})
$.post("/DoStuff", "{bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583}", function() {})
$.post("/DoStuff", "bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583", function() {})
```

There are no errors reported on this and similar approach used when I serialize a complex argument, does work.

Not sure how to trouble-shoot it.

Comment: Have you tried passing the name of the parameter as well? Something like `$.post("/DoStuff", "guid=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583", function() { ... });`. See the jquery [serialize docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @phoenixx Yes. It hits the method **but** the variable is null, still...

Comment: How about literally without any parentheses at all - `input=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583`. I've created a sample project locally and this is what gets posted - not `{input:yourinput}` or `{input=yourinput}` but `input=yourinput`. I get the guid passed into the method successfully that way.

Comment: @phoenixx So, just to be perfectly clear, your call looks like this: *$.post("/DoStuff", "input=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583", function() {})*, i.e. as a string, with the name of the parameter, equality sign and no brackets or colons?

Comment: Precisely. I've called my parameter 'guid' but yes, it is exactly as follows: `$.post("/DoStuff", "guid=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583", function(response) { console.log(response); }`. Also, I've taken a screenshot of my chrome network inspector so you can see what gets posted - see here [imgur link](http://imgur.com/v5rpInh).

Comment: I love you. Look at the first  line in my tested post calls. I was **so freaking** close. And yet so far. Issue resolved. Okay, maybe not "love" but definitely appreciate eagerly your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from @phoenixx I 'll answer and add some extra value by an observation. The correct post URL is as follows. (Note: a single string, parameter name - equality sign - parameter value, no braces, no brackets, no parentheses.)

```
$.post("/DoStuff", "input=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583", function() { });
```

It will issue the post if the method is in the right location in the directory structure and with the following signature.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoStuff(string input) { ... }
```

---

I've seen you refer to a variable `guid` and I suspect that you're trying to compose the call in JavaScript using the attributes of a DOM element invoking the call. If so, please note that the following will not work.

```
var guid = event.target.attributes["id"];
// guid is: id="bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583"
// you need: "id=bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583"
$.post("/DoStuff", guid, function() { });
```

See the tiny difference? It's a tricky pitfall and easy to get confused. You want the serialized version of the attribute like this.

```
var guid = event.target.attributes["id"];
$.post("/DoStuff", "id=" + guid.value, function() { });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to pass your key-value pair object as `json`:

```
var param = JSON.stringify({guid: 'bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583'});

$.post("/DoStuff", param, function() { ... }, 'json');
```

Note the last argument `'json'`.

The property name must reflect the argument name (guid). If your argument name is `id`, your property name must be `id`. This is applicable for all types. MVC works in an case-insensitive way (at the very least for MVC4), which is cool by the way.

Doing so the framework will try to parse your argument to the type you declared.

I consider the guid as a valid one; the framework will not parse it properly if the value is not a valid guid. For the sake of testing, ensure that `Guid.Parse("bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583")` will return an object `Guid`.

If you declare `DoStuff(string input) { }`, pass a key-value pair as follows:

```
var param = JSON.stringify({input: 'bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583'});
$.post("/DoStuff", param, function() { ... }, 'json'); //json dataType
```

Inside `DoStuff`, you could parse it as `Guid` using `Guid.Parse(input)`.

Comment: Tested a few variations myself, inclusing yours. Same fail. I'm receiving a string but it's null, all the time. It's like the framework can't see what to parse...

Comment: Interesting. It looks like this. requestUrl=http:/ /localhost:25760/ DoStuff& browserName=Chrome&userAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.106+Safari/537.36&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1452442511867

Comment: The above is from a page with no forms on it. When I invoke the same call from a page that has forms, it gives the value form the forms, not the string that I specified... The value doesn't have to be in a form for me to be able to post it in, does it?

Comment: You're right, there is no need to use a form to pass values to the server. Hidden parts of your code seems to interfere with the process.

Comment: So, I've invested a few minutes now to investigate what in the code on my side that might be causing the question. It seems that it isn't so, though. I noticed two things. First one is that the link request, as presented by the console, seems to be missing the provided parameter (so there's no way for the call to actually work, ever). That's done from the console in another browser, not from a script in the application. The error seems to be already there. The second one is that it works when I use serialization of the object in the form. The URL has then the data in it... What to do?!

Comment: You passed your parameters using form-urlencoded (url along with parameter e.g. dostuff?input=abc&param2=def). Keep it that way if it works. As an alternative use json. If so you must declare the latest argument 'json' in $.post from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the POST method with JQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

You can easiest pass lot of variable like that :

```
$.post( "/DoStuff", {input : "bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583" })
 .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

if you have a function:

```
function doStuff(myVarStringGuid){
    $.post( "/DoStuff", {input: myVarStringGuid})
     .done(function( data ) {
       alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });

}
```

On your PHP, you can get that variable like that :

```
$guid= $_POST['input'];    // bbbd861b-62ae-4eb5-9677-3aa2e354c583
```

If it's a C# you can get that variable like that:

```
string guid = Request.Form["input"];
```

Or with a Webmethod on codeBehind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DoStuff(string input)
{
    myInput = input;
}
```

But, the 500 error is when the server can be access to your page...
If your route http://yourWebsite/DoStuff  exist, it's probably because your object is nor serialized correctly.

Also, for send a form with JQuery, I use the plugin [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is very easy to send a form with Ajax with this: (and we gain lot of time^^ )

```
<form id="myForm" action="DoStuff" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="input" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>

<script>
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Guid was received ;-)"); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Don't forgot you can use the [browsers developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) for check your AJAX requests...

Comment: DoStuff(string input) is a method on your PHP? I edit my post :)

Comment: For not giving up +1. You might want to remove all your comments, as will I.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows 500 Internal server error. So, somewhere your code at the server is failing because you may not have passed the values properly or the server code itself is buggy.
When you do, form.serialize(), it produces a json structure of (key: value) pairs.

For example, "name": "Konrad" and at the server side you may accessed with

String name = request.getParameter("name");

**But in other case, you are passing only value and not the key. So, the above statement could not find the parameter "name" in the request.**
This is what I can figure out from your question, may be you can debug your server side code for better clarity.

**You need to send, {"guid": "WHATEVER_YOUR_VALUE"}**

Its always better to use serialize() if you are working with form. But serialize() has some restrictions like it cannot serialize some fields from form based on the tag you used.

Comment: I can see the pairs when I pass a complex, serialized object. But in this case, I want only to send a simple string. The receiving method has the signature *DoStuff(string input)*. What should I send in? I've tried both *string* and *input* but I get the same error...